# Include/exclude IDE-specific configuration files from Mercurial version control

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mercurial, config, configuration-files

The [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2017.2 [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-projects-under-version-control.html) suggests *including* the `.idea` folder that contains that [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)’s own configuration files (excepting the `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` files). I can understand the sense in this, as I could incorrectly configure the project settings and want to revert.

Yet, I want to post this open-source multi-module Maven-driven project to BitBucket for public access. Obviously, not everybody uses IntelliJ as their [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), so I do not want to force my IDE settings on them.

➠ How do open-source authors resolve this conundrum?

Comment: Can this question be posted on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I've no idea, as I have never been able to find guidance on Stack Overflow vs softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. No clear distinction has been drawn between them.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) (wrt this question specifically, see see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go))

Comment: @gnat The second Meta Question you linked suggests my Question might belong there on SE Stack Exchange. But it links to [a sibling Meta Question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6311/34735) that says just the opposite, claiming that no Git Questions belong on SE. As I said before, the SO-SE-Programmers site trio is a mess with no clear delineation, and what little guidance we have is contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion that comes from experience is to always explicitly ignore (that is, add to `.hgignore` or `.gitignore`) IDE configuration files or directories.

It is not only a question of not spamming a project with configuration files for a specific IDE. The real problem begins when more that one person uses the same IDE. Depending on the IDE and on how it is configured, you can fall in a situation where each commit contains changes to these files, and will confuse all the other developer using the same IDE, which in turn will overwrite the changes again in a infinite loop.

Some of your IDE settings will be global and stored in your home directory. The ones that are project specific will survive as long as you don't change the local directory in which you cloned the repo. If you change directory, in my experience it is always tolerable to reconfigure the IDE. There are at least two situations when the local directory changes: (1) you remove the directory and clone the repository again (2) you use more than one computer.

If you are concerned for things like coding style, then the best approach is to use a command-line formatter tool that works for any editor or IDE. That tool will have its configuration file committed in the repo, since coding style is something that should be equal for all developers and files of a repo.

Comment: Thanks, useful thoughts. Can you edit to explain more clearly what you mean about "change the local directory" in third paragraph?

Comment: I posted [this Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/46101/1255) asking about the command-line formatter tool you mentioned.

Comment: @BasilBourque updated the answer explaining better when a local directory can change