# Example '.hgignore' file for a Vaadin 8 project under Mercurial using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, vaadin, hgignore

I am seeking guidance as to what files and folders I might consider ignoring when placing a [*Vaadin Framework*](https://vaadin.com/framework) 8 project into version control using [*Mercurial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) with IntelliJ 2017 IDE. I am looking for examples of [`.hgignore`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore) files to use.

I want to avoid the unpleasantness of later wrestling with the version control system to get it to forget files which never should have been included in the repository.

I create my Vaadin projects via the [Maven archetypes provided](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/v8/getting-started/getting-started-archetypes.html) by the Vaadin.com team.

Answer (score 1):

While I am new to using Mercurial, here is what I've learned so far to ignore in my Vaadin projects.

The following are taken from my own `.hgignore` files using [`glob`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) syntax rather than the `regexp` syntax.

- `styles.scss.cache`
  Created when running the Maven lifecycle item `install`. I ignore this file per [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511711/642706) by Mika.
- `target`
  Ignores all the nested `target` folders re-populated when you build your Vaadin project. May have more than one, in a multi-module Maven project.
- `*.orig`
  Such files are created by Mercurial to preserve contents of files being replaced by restored versions. In my limited experience, it makes sense to leave these around for a while before eventually deleting them manually, never to be tracked by my Mercurial repository. You may decide otherwise.
- `*.idea`
  The folder where the [*IntelliJ*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) tracks the configuration of the project, such as the `Settings`/`Preferences` settings your may specify. The version control section of IntelliJ documentation suggests you include all but two files from this folder in your version-control system. That probably makes sense if you are sure to be working solo, never sharing development with a team or an open-source project. But if there is any chance of sharing, then I choose to ignore entirely the IntelliJ settings from my Mercurial repository, per [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46504613/642706) by marco.m. Note that you may have more than one of these folders in a multi-module project.
- `*.iml`
  Ditto for `*.idea` above. This is the IntelliJ file for tracking your project.
- `.DS_Store`
  A [`.DS_Store`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) file is generated spontaneously by Apple [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) to track the arrangement of a folder. If there is any possibility of a Mac being involved with your project, include this to be ignored.

Here is an example of my `.hgignore` file.

```bash
syntax: glob
.DS_Store
*.orig
target
*.idea
*.iml
styles.scss.cache
```

**Tip:** After first running `hg init` to create your repository, you can create your `.hgignore` file, then check its effects by running `hg status`. The result of the status check lists all the files being considered by Mercurial. You can edit the ignore list and re-run the `hg status` to see the effects of your edits. Lather, rinse, repeat, without affecting your repository. Your new fresh repository remains pure and unaffected until running something like `hg add` and `hg commit`.

Comment: How is intellij stuff relevant to the question? Dito for OSX files? Not a mercurial user here, but `.orig` (and `.rej`) sound like a patch-gone-bad artifact and i'd rather see them and deal with them.

Comment: The goal of the Question is to avoid files in the first place rather than "forget" them in the repository later. The `.orig` file extension on file copies is default behavior of the current version of Mercurial. As for the .DS_Store, as I said if there is any possibility of a Mac being involved, you'll not want that file. You could skip that item, but it certainly does not hurt to include it to be on the safe side. As for the IntelliJ, that happens to be my current IDE. The point is for you to adjust to exclude (or include) your own IDE’s project tracking files and folders.

Comment: I know why to want those files in there, but i think they are cluttering up the answer.  You want to have those files in "every" project of yours.  And non OSX, non intellij users, will want to have others.

Comment: @cfrick Point taken. I edited the Question to be clear it is IntelliJ-specific. I had not thought it through to realize a complete answer to my question must be IDE-specific.